# Centering and image size in split screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on a project using split screen CSS and I'm having trouble both with image size and positioning. I've used the .centered CSS as instructed by W3schools, but it keeps offsetting the image and text to the right of the 'left split'. What am I doing wrong. I'm trying to center the image and the accompany `<h2>` text. W3schools shows one solution, which I've worked around for a few hours. I'm a newbie to coding and not really sure how to search for a solution. Any advice and pointers would be welcomed.

```html
<body>
<!-- left side -->
    <div class="split left">
        <div class="centered">
            <img src="images/stufgreenthumb500.png" alt="stuf logo">
            <h2 style="text-align: center;">Bid on items to support local & National Organizations</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- right side -->
    <div class="split right">
        <h3 style="text-align: center;">Bid on these Items</h3>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row row-content">
                    <!-- Card 1 -->
                    <div class="col-md-4 d-flex">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <dl class="row">
                                <h6>Star Wars Script</h6>
                                <img src="images/starwarsscript.jpg" class="img-thumbnail mx-auto" alt="star wars script">
                                <dt class="col-8">Value:</dt>
                                <dd class="col-4">$15,000</dd>
                                <dt class="col-8">Donor:</dt>
                                <dd class="col-4">George Lucas</dd>
                                <dt class="col-8">Opening Bid:</dt>
                                <dd class="col-4">$10,000</dd>
                                <dt class="col-8">Bid Increment:</dt>
                                <dd class="col-4">$1,000</dd>
                                <dt class="col-8">Supporting:</dt>
                                <dd class="col-4">Feeding America</dd>
                            <div class="card-footer-fluid mx mx-auto">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Bid</button>
                            </div>
                            </dl>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Card 2 -->
                    <div class="col-md-4 d-flex" class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <dl class="row">
                                <h6>Signed Air Jordans</h6>
                            <img src="images/jordanshoes.jpg" class="img-thumbnail mx-auto" alt="air jordans">
                            <dt class="col-8">Value:</dt>
                            <dd class="col-4">$10,000</dd>
                            <dt class="col-8">Donor:</dt>
                            <dd class="col-4">Michael Jordan</dd>
                            <dt class="col-8">Opening Bid:</dt>
                            <dd class="col-4">$3,000</dd>
                            <dt class="col-8">Bid Increment:</dt>
                            <dd class="col-4">$500</dd>
                            <dt class="col-8">Supporting:</dt>
                            <dd class="col-4">Americans Thrive</dd>
                            <div class="card-footer-fluid mx mx-auto">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Bid</button>
                            </div>
                            </dl>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Card 3 -->
                    <div class="col-md-4 d-flex" class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <dl class="row">
                            <h6>Tiger's Sunday Jersey</h6>
                            <img src="images/woodsjersey.jpeg" class="img-thumbnail mx-auto" alt="Tiger Woods Polo">
                            <dt class="col-8">Value:</dt>
                            <dd class="col-4">$1,000</dd>
                            <dt class="col-8">Donor:</dt>
                            <dd class="col-4">Tiger Woods</dd>
                            <dt class="col-8">Opening Bid:</dt>
                            <dd class="col-4">$500</dd>
                            <dt class="col-8">Bid Increment:</dt>
                            <dd class="col-4">$100</dd>
                            <dt class="col-8">Supporting:</dt>
                            <dd class="col-4">Salvation Army America</dd>
                            <div class="card-footer-fluid mx mx-auto">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Bid</button>
                            </div>
                            </dl>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Card 4 -->
                    <div class="col-md-4" class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <dl class="row">
                                <h6>Lakers-Celtics Floor Seats</h6>
                                <img src="images/floortickets.jpg" class="img-thumbnail mx-auto" alt="lakers floor tickets">
                                <dt class="col-8">Value:</dt>
                                <dd class="col-4">$1,000</dd>
                                <dt class="col-8">Donor:</dt>
                                <dd class="col-4">The LA Lakers</dd>
                                <dt class="col-8">Opening Bid:</dt>
                                <dd class="col-4">$300</dd>
                                <dt class="col-8">Bid Increment:</dt>
                                <dd class="col-4">$100</dd>
                                <dt class="col-8">Supporting:</dt>
                                <dd class="col-4">Operation Hope</dd>
                                <div class="card-footer-fluid mx mx-auto">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Bid</button>
                                </div>
                            </dl>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Card 5 -->
                    <div class="col-md-4" class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <dl class="row">
                                <h6>Signed Joshua Tree</h6>
                                <img src="images/u2.jpg" class="img-thumbnail mx-auto" alt="lakers floor tickets">
                                <dt class="col-6">Value:</dt>
                                <dd class="col-6">$1,000</dd>
                                <dt class="col-6">Donor:</dt>
                                <dd class="col-6">Bono/U2</dd>
                                <dt class="col-6">Opening Bid:</dt>
                                <dd class="col-6">$300</dd>
                                <dt class="col-6">Bid Increment:</dt>
                                <dd class="col-6">$100</dd>
                                <dt class="col-6">Supporting:</dt>
                                <dd class="col-6">Operation Hope</dd>
                                <div class="card-footer-fluid mx mx-auto">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Bid</button>
                                </div>
                            </dl>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Card 6 -->
                    <div class="col-md-4" class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <dl class="row">
                            <h6>Signed Chipper Jones Bat</h6>
                            <img src="images/jones.jpg" class="img-thumbnail mx-auto" alt="lakers floor tickets">
                            <dt class="col-8">Value:</dt>
                            <dd class="col-4">$500</dd>
                            <dt class="col-8">Donor:</dt>
                            <dd class="col-4">Chipper Jones</dd>
                            <dt class="col-8">Opening Bid:</dt>
                            <dd class="col-4">$100</dd>
                            <dt class="col-8">Bid Increment:</dt>
                            <dd class="col-4">$50</dd>
                            <dt class="col-8">Supporting:</dt>
                            <dd class="col-4">Bread For Tomorrow</dd>
                            <div class="card-footer-fluid mx mx-auto">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Bid</button>
                            </div>
                            </dl>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
<!-- footer -->

</body>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please put in the bootstrap-4 CSS path and also place your code into the stack overflow code snippet so it is runnable to show result?

Answer (score 0):

Setting horizontal margin to `auto` will do trick for you, it needs a width to be specified.

```css
.split {
  width: 49%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  float: left;
}

.centered {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.centered img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="split">
  <div class="centered">
    <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/83/200/100.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="split">

</div>
```